# how to change background color when I click the button using react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React project, In that I have App.js component, in that component I have button Now please tell me how to change button background color and button text color by using react hooks

This is App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
  function App() {
  const [color,setColor]=useState('red');
  const [textColor,setTextColor]=useState('white');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button style={{background:color,color:textColor}} className='btn btn-primary' onClick={()=>{setColor("black");setTextColor('red')}}>Click here</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

OR
check link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x7mevv

Answer (score 1):

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [toggle,setToggle] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleIt =()=>{
    setToggle(!toggle)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <button onClick={toggleIt}>{toggle?'Hide':'Show'}</button>
     <div className={toggle ? 'body-color': ''}>
      Body
     </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

class in **App.css**

```
.body-color{
  background: coral;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';

function App() {

 const [color, setColor] = useState("white");  // default value of bg-color 
 const [textColor, setText] = useState("black");  // default value of text-color

 function Clicked() {
  setColor("black");
  setText("white");
  }

  return (
  <div className="App">

  <button
    style={{ background: color, color: textColor }}
    onClick={Clicked}                  // function is called to change the color
    className="btn btn-primary">

     Click here

     </button>
     </div>
     );
```